# Find the point of intersection of the two tangents at the end points of the latusrectum of the parabola $(y+3)^2=8(x-2)$

Tags: conic-sections

Equation of latusrectum

$$X-a=0$$$$x-2-2=0$$
$$x=4$$

Therefore 
$$(y+3)^2=8(4-2)$$
$$y=1,-7$$
Then point from which tangents are drawn are 
$(4,1)$ and $(4,-7)$.

Their point intersection will $(-4,-3)$, using the GM and AM property of point of intersection of tangent.

The answer is (0,-3). How is the right answer?

Comment: Do you know about pole-polar relationships? This point is the pole of the latus rectum. It also happens to be the intersection of the axis and directrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the tangent of the parabola is,

$$y' = \frac4{y+3}$$

So, at the two ends of the latus rectum with $y=1,-7$, they are $y'= 1,-1$, respectively. Hence, the corresponding equations of the two tangent lines are,

$$y-1=x-4,\>\>\>\>\>\>y+7 = -1(x-4)$$

They intersect at the point $(0,-3)$.

Comment: What is $y’$ and why is $y’=\frac{4}{y+3}$?

Comment: @Aditya - take the derivative of $(y+3)^2=8(x-2)$ on both sides to get $2(y+3)y’=8$. Then, rearrange

Comment: Okay, what’s wrong with my approach? All did was some fairly straightforward substitution

Comment: @Aditya - Your approach is correct up to the point "Then point from which tangents are drawn are $(4,1)$ and $(4,-7)$". It's unclear from the post what you did afterwards

Comment: I used a well-known property point of intersection of two tangents drawn to a parabola is (GM of abscissa, AM of ordinates)

Comment: @Aditya - The way you used the property implicitly assumes that the $x$-coordinate of the vertex is 0, which is not the case here.

Comment: Right. Then how should I modify the property to match the transformation, or is it just not possible?

Comment: @Aditya - The generalized property states that the abscissa of the tangent intersection is $-(\frac p2 - x_0)$, where $p$ and $x_0$ are the $x$-coordinates of the focus and vertex, respectively. In your case $p=4$ and $x_0=2$.

Comment: I would like to note this down. What will be the case in for ordinates?

Comment: @Aditya - The case for ordinates remains the same, i.e. still the average of ordinates

Comment: What if it’s the form of $(x-h)^2=4a(y-k)^2$ ie. pointing upwards rather than rightwards? Will y change then?

Comment: @Aditya - Then, you just switch the coordinates for the intersection, i.e. its $y$-coordinate become $-(\frac p2 - y_0)$.